# Multiple Spring WEB MVC versions in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I totally new with `Spring MVC` and just started learning it 3 days ago. I'm still trying to understand it's configuration. I would like to know if it's advisable and possible to have multiple dependency definitions in `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
    <artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I know this may be a simple question but I need to know if this is a good practice or not.

I noticed that when I tried to use the `4.3.3 RELEASE` it didn't generate the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `applicationContext.xml` files inside the `WEB-INF` folder. But when I used the 4.2.4 `RELEASE` it generated the two files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice, because it's better to be explicit in which versions to use.

Maven will just omit one of the versions. You can use the Maven dependency plugin to see which ones are selected:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```